How do I train an assistant api on yelp dataset using OpenAi api dashboard?
I have the yelp acedemic dataset, if possible I would like to find another new dataset that maybe more up to date and includes all businesses in New York State. So right now with the dataset i have it is all in json files, and I am not sure how to train the assistant I am creating for my api for my webpage. Does anyone know how I can train a model?
I have tried converting the json files into jsonl but they are extremely large and i am having trouble converting them. Everytime I put the json files into the file storage it will work on some and fail on others that are too big i presume becasue they are 5.2 million KB. Even when the files that have like 160k KB manage to get through the downloading stage, they fail to be indexed. Does anyone have any steps I can take to actually teach a model and use it for my api ?
